# juniper router /var directory is full , deleting .tgz file in root directory

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos, linux, memory

i need to free some space on my juniper router , in the root directory when i use >ls -lash command i see a .tgz file which is 405 M , my question , if i delete this will it cause any problem ?

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Juniper built a specific command for cleaning up files.

`request system storage cleanup` and `request system storage cleanup dry-run`

The documentation is [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/request-system-storage-cleanup.html), but basically it's for doing exactly what you want - deleting unnecessary files.  I tend to just use `dry-run` and manually delete a handful if I'm even slightly concerned about it.  While it's *a bit liberal*, it will never delete anything critical to the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete that file.  Someone most likely left it there by mistake after a software upgrade.